# How to get a body part to always stay attached to the center of another with an armature?

Tags: rigging, armature, bones

I have an issue when rigging a mech character (im a complete rigging novice):

I have these 2 metallic bars that are attaching the thigh with the joints of the lower leg. I have a bone for the thigh, 1 for the 2 metallic bars (maybe I could use 2?), and then 1 for the lower leg (Image 1).

You can see in Image 2 that when I move the leg forward, the mesh if moved with it, but the metallic bars are not lining up with the round joints anymore. That makes sense, but how to I fix that? What kind of constraints am I looking for so that these bars will always be pointing towards the center of these joints?

Image 1:
[image]

Image 2:
[image]

Thanks.